# Mapping two dictionaries with same properties in asp .net core

Tags: c#, dictionary, asp.net-core, mapping

I am using Mapping object in asp.net core 6. Currently, I want to map two dictionaries in the asp .net core, one has value in key = null and one has value in key != null.

You can see my code below:

```
    public async Task<IDictionary<string, object>> MappingDictionaries(IDictionary<string, object> sourceDict)
    {
        // Get dictionary from Repository, this dictionary has value in key = null;
        var destinationDict = await _myRepository.GetMulti(x => x.ParentID == 0);
        // sourceDict is passed by parameter variable and this dictionary has value != null;
    }
```

How can I map properties and values from **sourceDict** to **destinationDict**? To check if the properties have been mapped, if yes return **destinationDict**, otherwise show a notification error.

My source dictionary:

```
"customerInfo": { 
    "CustomerName": "A", 
    "CustomerCode": "ABC", 
    "DateOfBirdth": "12/02/2020", 
    "Address": "D", 
    "PhoneNumber": "12345", 
    "Gender": "Nam", 
    "Email": "abc" 
}, 
"provideTime": { 
    "Hour": "12:00", 
    "Day": "07", 
    "Month": "10", 
    "Year": "2022" 
}
```

My destination dictionary:

```
"customerInfo": { 
    "CustomerName": "", 
    "CustomerCode": "", 
    "DateOfBirdth": "", 
    "Address": "", 
    "PhoneNumber": "", 
    "Gender": "", 
    "Email": "" 
}, 
"provideTime": { 
    "Hour": "", 
    "Day": "", 
    "Month": "", 
    "Year": "" 
}
```

Thanks for your support and sorry for my bad English!

Comment: I would need some further information. Can I expect the Dictionaries to have the same length? Why you use two Dictionaries instead of two Lists? Is Keys[0].Key the Key of Destination[0]?

Comment: Yes. I'm using two dictionaries because my "sourceDict" is a dynamic object, it is shorter or has the same properties length as my "destinationDict". Two of my dictionary has the same properties name

Comment: Could you give an example of what sourceDict and destinationDict should look like?

Comment: Yes, of course!

My source dictionary 
  "customerInfo": {
    "CustomerName": "A",
    "CustomerCode": "ABC",
    "DateOfBirdth": "12/02/2020",
    "Address": "D",
    "PhoneNumber": "12345",
    "Gender": "Nam",
    "Email": "abc"
  },
  "provideTime": {
    "Hour": "12:00",
    "Day": "07",
    "Month": "10",
    "Year": "2022"
  }

Comment: And my destination dictionary 

  "customerInfo": {
    "CustomerName": "",
    "CustomerCode": "",
    "DateOfBirdth": "",
    "Address": "",
    "PhoneNumber": "",
    "Gender": "",
    "Email": ""
  }
  "provideTime": {
    "Hour": "",
    "Day": "",
    "Month": "",
    "Year": ""
  }

Comment: Your example dictionaries don't look like dictionaries of string, object. Is that just the object part? If so, what would the keys be? What you've got looks like json objects, which if that's the case, why not just deserialize them into an IEnumerbale of CustomerInfo or some other type of custom object?

Comment: First, my dictionary key is "CustomerName" and "provideTime" value is an object. And then , my dictionary key is "CustomerName", "CustomerCode", "DateOfBirdth".... in my sample the value is a string but maybe it has an object type. My example is Dictionary inside the Dictionary

Comment: What advantage do you achieve by parsing your object into a Dictionary?

Comment: Is the destinationDict always going to have the same schema? So you're trying to fit what values you have from your sourceDict into the destinationDict, but it may fill nothing or all of it.

Comment: Yesss. The destination may have a null value but all of the source value properties have to fill into the destination value properties. I used Automapper to map the source and destination, it worked, but lost destination properties when the source schema was shorter than the destination. The result only has source properties

Comment: This is normal of AutoMapper. When the source schema is shorter than the destination, the extra part cannot be matched by default, so it will not be mapped to the destination. You can take a look at [this GitHub](https://github.com/SlapperAutoMapper/Slapper.AutoMapper).